# Pick file from Custom gallery of Audio and Video files

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created a `Gallery Activity` which contains list of audio and video files located on SD Card. I have another activity through which I want to pick files from `Gallery Activity` using `Intent`. I have added following `intent-filter` to manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activities.GalleryActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/gallery"
            android:label="@string/gallery"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activities.MainActivity">

            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Here is how I have created `Intent` to pick file:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, ATTACH_FILES);
```

**EDITS:
Here is item `onClickListener` of `Gallery Activity`:**

```
viewAdapter.withOnClickListener(new FastAdapter.OnClickListener<GalleryRowContent>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClick(View v, IAdapter<GalleryRowContent> adapter, GalleryRowContent item, int position) {

                if (adapter.getFastAdapter().getSelections().size() == 0) {

                    if (item.getTag().equals("audio")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        File file = new File(item.getFilePath());
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else if (item.getTag().equals("video")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        File file = new File(item.getFilePath());
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

This code shows my app in intent chooser and also opens `Gallery Activity`, however when I click on any file, it opens the file intead of picking it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Presumably, you wrote `GalleryActivity` to open the file when the user clicks on an item. If that is not what you want, change it. If you do not know how to change it, show the code from `GalleryActivity` that you execute when the user clicks on an item.

Comment: yes. So how do I differentiate between click to open file and click to pick file???

Comment: added `onClickListener` of `Gallery Activity`. @CommonsWare

Comment: may be I should use `if-else` block on `intent.getAction()`. In that case, how should I return file `Uri`?? @CommonsWare

Comment: Replace your calls to `startActivity()` with paired calls to `setResult()` and `finish()`. `setResult()` is how you return a result for use with `startActivityForResult()`, as is covered by [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

Comment: it worked!! Thanks a ton man! This is exactly what I was looking for.. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a result from an activity started by `startActivityForResult()`, call `setResult()`, supplying the `Intent` containing the "result". Usually, this is immediately followed by a call to `finish()`, so control returns to the activity that had called `startActivityForResult()`, so it can use the result.